# Drop Down menu going up instead of down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Somehow my drop down menu isn't going down but is going to the top: http://fawky.de/fawky/powerbikes/index.html This is my full CSS, is something blocking it from going down?
Using top:50px; didn't work either.

http://pastebin.com/YqifT4JW

Thanks.

Comment: Here's [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it's a great site for posting (client-side, HTML/JavaScript/CSS) code and showing that code in action. There are, of course, many others like it. Incidentally, reduce your code as far as you can so that it still demonstrates your problem, and post that code with your question. That way if the external site dies, or cleans up its archives, the question is still useful in future.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove `position:absolute` from `.topmenu li`. Then you should use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;` to hide the submenus. This way the submenu is hidden but the space for it is reserved ([more info](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp))

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:absolute` from `.topmenu li`

Comment: Thanks, but then the nav moves to the side to make room for the menu and that's what I was trying to stop. I updated it: http://fawky.de/fawky/powerbikes/index.html Example what I mean: http://www.audi.com/com/brand/en.html

Comment: @Fawky the menu items in  audi.com/com/brand/en.html are of fixed width. You need to specify the width for #menu li.topmenu and #menu li.topmenu ul.

Comment: Almost. #menu li.topmenu worked and fixxed it, but the space between them are diffrent now. #menu li.topmenu ul didn't change anything...